# Помогите с решение задачи

Tags: python-3.x

Задача звучит так:
В бригаде, работающей на уборке сена, имеется N косилок. Первая из них работа M часов, а каждая следующая на 10 минут больше, чем предыдущая. Сколько часов проработала вся бригада.

Вот исходный код

```
#coding: utf - 8
косилки = int(input("Кол-во косилок \n"))
время_работы = int(input("Время работы этой косилки\n"))

time = 0       
iterator = 0 
while iterator < косилки:

time = time + 10
общее_время = время_работы + time
iterator += 1     
print(общее_время)
```

Если указывать время в минутах т.е. время работы указывать к примеру 60, а число косилок 3, то по идеи должно получаться 120, а получается 90.

Так вот почему в конце цикла именно самое последнее число из time (т.е. 30) прибавляется к времени работы.

Comment: Должно получаться 90, а не 120. 90 и получается.

Answer (score 1):

Если каждая косилка в бригаде из N косилок проработала по одному часу, то сколько проработала вся бригада? Не могу понять вопроса. Если они работали одновременно с 9:00 до 10:00 то вся бригада работала 1 час?  Или бригада проработала N часов? А если по очереди? И в примере откуда 120 или 90? Первая работает 60, вторая 70, третья 80 минут... Вместе 210 минут... По моему условие нуждается в уточнении...
В таком виде я бы сделал хотябы так:

```
#coding: utf - 8
косилки = int(input("Кол-во косилок \n"))
время_работы = int(input("Время работы этой косилки\n"))

time = 0       
iterator = 0 
while iterator < косилки:
   iterator += 1   
   общее_время = время_работы + time
   time = time + 10

   print(iterator,общее_время)
```

Comment: Тройка лошадей, запряженная в карету, проскакала 50 километров. Сколько проскакала каждая лошадь?

Comment: Каждая следующая лошадь скакала на 10 минут дольше... ;) Ну или на 3 км больше... Остальные подъехали на одной... Масса вариантов... Хорошая у нас бригада: Один с сошкой - семеро с ложкой. Что делали остальные косилки когда последняя докашивала? Зарплату поровну?

Comment: По формуле M * N * 60 + 10 * (N - 1) * N / 2 = 1*3*60+5*2*6=180+30=210. Перевести на лошадей - телега проехала 150 км...

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, бригада - это когда все работали вместе. Т.е. при любом количестве косилок бригада проработала M часов при условии, что они начали работу одновременно... ;) Т.к. если Вася весь день работал, а петя пришел ему помочь на два часа, то их бригада из двух человек Пети и Васи работала два часа...

Comment: "Должно получиться 120" Это Вы в ответе подсмотрели? Может это 1:20 и тогда всё схдится - 80 минут...

Answer (score 0):

```
M * N * 60 + 10 * (N - 1) * N / 2 # косилко-минут, разделить на 60 для косилко-часов
```